# How to block all ip's which are not in ipset list

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, ip

I am trying to block all traffic except US and Canada. I added all US and Canada IP's to ipset geoblock and when i am trying this command. I am getting an error.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --set !geoblock src -j DROP
-bash: !geoblock: event not found
```

but when i run this command

```
ipset list
```

I am getting all the IP's, so there is nothing wrong with the name and the ipset.
I am using iptables v1.4.21 on cent os 7.3.1611

Comment: The fact that you are getting a **bash** error makes me think  you need to escape your `!`.  But I am not sure.

Answer (score 6):

## Solution:

Following is the correct command line:

**`iptables -A INPUT -m set ! --match-set geoblock src -j DROP`**

## Explanation:

```
javier@equipo-javier:~$ sudo ipset create geoblock hash:net
javier@equipo-javier:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set --set '!geoblock' src -j DROP
--set option deprecated, please use --match-set
iptables v1.4.21: Set !geoblock doesn't exist.

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

1st correction:

```
javier@equipo-javier:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set '!geoblock' src -j DROP
iptables v1.4.21: Set !geoblock doesn't exist.

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

2nd correction:

```
javier@equipo-javier:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set ! --match-set geoblock src -j DROP
javier@equipo-javier:~$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m set ! --match-set geoblock src -j DROP
```

Now works

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you tried putting a space between ! and geoblock then iptables would have also informed you of the correct syntax.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to get that iptables' output suggesting the correct syntax. Could you copy an example here?

Comment: Sure, my ipset lists are called whitelist and geoblock. I'm using ipset v6.11 and iptables 1.4.7 `/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set whitelist src,dst -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 2 -m set --match-set geoblock src,dst -j DROP`

Answer (score 1):

As Zoredache mentioned the `bash` error indicates this is a quoting issue.  Putting that argument in single quotes or using backslash to escape the exclamation will get around the immediate issue:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --set '!geoblock' src -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --set \!geoblock src -j DROP
```